# Is USB tethered connection routed through VPN?

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, android, tethering

Suppose I am using USB tethering from my android to connect my PC to Internet. If I set up a VPN on android using Psiphon, will my PC traffic be routed through the VPN? If not, how can I set it up for the same?

Comment: As per me, it will surely be routed through vpn only .

Comment: As far as I know, Android prevents any VPN connection to be used by tethering devices. (May not be true if it is of very old version though.)

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216050/218526

Answer (score 0):

Use any Android proxy application (for example, Every Proxy) to start a server (HTTP/HTTPS may be an option).

On the PC which is routed via tethered connection, simply edit manual proxy settings with this server IP and port. It's not perfectly reliable and may get down randomly, but enough for temporary operations.